# Custom Sort using terminal on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, sorting, terminal

**Background**

I have a folder with a bunch of files. They are labeled as follows:

1. YO_c1
2. gg_d1
3. boom_a5
4. head_v4
5. shot_o0

**Question**

I want to sort the files alphabetically, using the letter after the underscore. Is there a way to do this using terminal on MAC OSX?

In the end, it should look like this:

1. boom_a5
2. YO_c1
3. gg_d1
4. shot_o0
5. head_v4

Thanks!
these are dummy files and i have about 600 files that i want to sort this way PLEASE HELP

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague... Also, are all of the files in one folder?

Comment: yes they are in one folder

Comment: Do you need the shell command to change the order of the folder in Finder, or simply output it as a list: `myFolder = boom_a5, YO_c1...`?

Comment: change the order in finder  not output as a list

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try:

ls | sort -k 2 -t "_"